# How to post on all my friends walls using facebook graph api?

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

In my application I have a requirement of posting to all my friends walls .I used the following code to do this:

```
    final int postCount = friends_facebookids.size();

            new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                if(postCount==0){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Add friends to post", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                for(int m=0;m<friends_facebookids.size();m++){
                String res=  UrltoValue.getValuefromUrl("https://graph.facebook.com/"+friends_facebookids.get(m)+"/feed?access_token="+accesstoken+"&method="+"post"+"&message="+strFullMessage.replaceAll(" ", "%20")+"&source="+imageUrl);
                Log.e("post response",res);
                   counter +=1;

                }


                if(counter>=postCount){

                    cancel();//stops the timer
                    counter=0;
                }


            }
        }, 1000,3000);
```

Here I am giving 3sec delay between each request, so that I can post to multiple friends walls without any restrictions from Facebook.

It worked for me upto 25 friends, after that I am getting  (Bad Request as Response).
Do I need to change anything in my code? Why is there an apprent restriction after 25 posts to Facebook.

Answer (score 2):

This is highly spammy for 2 reasons, among others:

**1)** You are posting the same message on everyone's wall, without regard to who it is actually relevant to. = SPAM

**2)** You are making it a "requirement". Strictly forbidden in the developers TOS.

Word of advice: Stop NOW. If your app hasn't been shut down yet, I hope it happens soon.

Comment: Posting to friend’s walls via API will be disabled February 6, 2013 anyway … and, funny thing, for the reason that, quote: Post to friends wall via the API generate a high levels of negative user feedback, including “Hides” and “Mark as Spam" and so we are removing it from the API.

Comment: can I know where it is mentioned in facebook developers site

Comment: All these changes can be found in the Roadmap: https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/